При парсинге через BeautifulSoup, в ответе приходит None
Мне нужно спарсить самую свежую новость которая вышла на сайте (нужен только заголовок новости) https://www.ea.com/ru-ru/games/apex-legends/news#game-updates но в ответ приходит None, делаю тоже самое с другими сайтами и все нормально парсится
Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема?
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_apex = 'https://www.ea.com/ru-ru/games/apex-legends/news#game-updates'

response = requests.get(url_apex)
html_content = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
h3_element = soup.find('h3', class_='eapl-tile__title h5 h5-light')

print(h3_element)



Вас не смущает, что переменная у вас называется html_content, а из response вы берёте не content, а text? Не факт, что в этом всё дело, но всё-таки.

@чистов_n-заРоссию я пробовал и content и text. На имя переменной можете не обращать внимание, я забыл его поменять наверное. Но в любом случае, приходит None или пустой список

В response.text не существует тег h3' с классом eapl-tile__title h5 h5-light, requests не браузер.

Ну видимо там на JS сайт во многом написан, придётся вам Selenium использовать для эмуляции браузера.
